# How to crawl an ajax generate web page?

Tags: php, python, web-crawler

i have try to crawl https://world.taobao.com/search/search.htm?cat=50008090&_ksTS=1461999216322_20&spm=a21bp.7806943.banner_XX_cat.13.UxfRzO&_input_charset=utf-8&navigator=all&json=on&callback=__jsonp_cb&cna=CKNtDjuNxTgCAdIGQMzvfvwH&abtest=_AB-LR517-LR854-LR895-PR517-PR854-PV895_2462

but not success, the reponse page source not match the view page,any one know how to do?Thanks

Comment: Which crawler are you using?

Comment: I have tried php-curl,Thanks for reply

Comment: php-curl will not solve this problem as php can not execute JS code. You have to use some library like phantomjs to capture content loaded by JS

Comment: Thanks , i will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use some library where JS content can be captured that's why `php-curl` will not work here.

You can use various libraries like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/)